# Debugging/Stepping into Windows Store API Source

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-debugging

In Visual Studio, I am able to step through .net framework source code: [Debug .NET Framework Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc667410.aspx)

However I was unable to step through Windows Store API components in my code. Is this possible?

And Would there be any way to step into the constructor of an object in the Windows.UI.Xaml namespace when that object gets created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of yet, MSFT has not yet released the source files for the .NET Core (used by Windows Store). Last I heard, there haven't been any announcements about releasing the code, but that does not mean that it won't be released in the future.

Comment: I see, well hopefully it does get released in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but you may try turning off "Just My Code" in your debug options.  I doubt they include the source though so you are likely out of luck.

Comment: Just My Code seems to be off but I think you are correct about not including the source for Windows Store APIs